# Does it make sense to say a computer needs core 5 to display video from a camera (Cannon SX720HS) correctly?

Tags: camera

The video on our computer stutters or flickers. Cannon help and a computer tech told my wife that it is because our computer is 3 cores  and you need 5 cores really core i5 which is quite different of course- most core i5 are 4 cores and low ends are 3 or 2 cores. Does that make sense- why isn't it just you need more computer power or graphics power? What is requirements to show directly from the camera- wife is so cryptic?

Answer (score 0):

No. That really doesn't make sense.

- Faster is better, yes, but often the bottleneck is disk io.
- More cores should also be better as well, to prevent other applications causing stuttering.
- Faster core speed is better too.

But running video from a camera can be done on much older machines so the tech is talking nonsense.

Comment: "But running video from a camera can be done on much older machines..." not to mention the camera itself, which probably doesn't have a multicore processor.